# Validar un formulario con django

Tags: python, django, formularios

Estoy en mi primer proyecto montado en un servidor y he elegido el framework django.
Estoy haciendo una aplicación que muestra valores de una base de datos de minerales que he hecho, y que tiene un campo de búsqueda con la etiqueta form:

```
<div class="container" style="width:75%;margin:auto;padding:10px">
  <form style="width:75%;margin:auto" type="get" action="./../result" style="margin: 0" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Mineral o grupo..." >
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="search_submit" type="submit" >Buscar mineral o grupo</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

En la view tengo:

```
def result(request):
valorpasado=str(request.get_full_path).replace("<bound method WSGIRequest.get_full_path of <WSGIRequest: GET '/result/?","")
valorpasado=valorpasado.replace("'>>","")
if request.method == 'GET': # If the form is submitted
    dicty = {
        "minerales":Mine180.objects,
        "search_query":request.GET.get('search_box', None),
        "valorpasado":valorpasado

    }


    return render(request,'mine180/result.html',{'dicty':dicty})
```

La ruta la tengo configurada así en urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

  url(r'^result/$',viewmine.result, name='result'),

]
```

Si el  resultado introducido es un mineral de la lista todo correcto, muestro el resultado en la ruta del action 'domain/result/?query
Pero no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien, pues si no coincide con ningún mineral debe permanecer en la página.
No comprendo muy bien dónde debo hacer la validación, si en el modelo o en la view. He intentado algunas cosas como redirigir para la ruta original si la query no coincide, pero no cre que sea este el método correcto.

## Por si alguien cae por aquí y le interesa, conseguí implementar lo que necesitaba rápidamente gracias a la ayuda de Germán.

Y mi urls.py queda:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^mine180/ficha/(?P<mine_id>[0-9]+)/$',viewmine.ficha),
url(r'^mine180/consulta/',viewmine.consulta),
]
```

el form conduce a mine180/consulta con signo ? :

```
<form style="width:75%;margin:auto" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/mine180/consulta/?" method="get">
<input size="40"id="search_mine" type="text" name="search_mine" value="{{ current_name }}" placeholder="Busque mineral o grupo...">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
```

y en la función de la view que gestiona la consulta (def consulta), tomo la query. Lo tengo que mejorar, pero el código mostrado, si la búsqueda coincide con un mineral de la DB, abre el template de la ficha (y el template recibe parámetros del mineral en concreto, como el id); si no lo encuentra retorna el template original del search_box, añadiendo un mensaje de que no ha encontrado el mineral.
Aquí puedo implementar los filtros de búsqueda, tal y como me ha indicado Germán, y lo haré.

```
def consulta(request):
#desde search_box
query = request.GET.get('search_mine', '')
mineid = 0
for mineral in Mine180.objects.all():
    if mineral.name1==query:
        print 'encontro oro'
        mineid = mineral.id
        print mineid
#print 'viene de consulta'
if mineid != 0:
    print 'lo encontro'
    return render(request,'mine180/ficha.html',{'mineid':mineid})
else:
    print 'No lo encontro'
    minerales = {
        "minerales":Mine180.objects,
        "mensaje":"No se encontro el mineral: "+query
    }
    return render(request,'mine180/mine180.html',minerales)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno te ayudaré para explicarte varios puntos.

Primero es el atributo `action` del tag `form`, este atributo lo que hace es decirle al navegador que todos los campos que estén en ese formulario, al escuchar un evento `submit` los enviará a una ruta o url determinada, en este caso sería `/result/` que fue lo que definiste en tu archivo de **urls.py**; Django te ofrece una forma de hacer esto un poco más rápido y de una forma más escalable con el template tag `{% url 'result' %}`, donde `result` debe estar igual de escrito que el valor que le pones al atributo `name` de la url que quieres llamar.

Luego en tu vista, veo que haces un `str(request.get_full_path)`. Usualmente por convenciones, en python y django, cuando algo empieza por `get` hace referencia a un método, y no a una propiedad. Lo que sucede aquí es que estás llamando a una representación de un método y no al método como tal, recuerda que los métodos deben ser llamados, puedes comprobar si algo es un método o una función con la función que python trae para ti, llamada `callable`, de la siguiente forma:

```
if callable(request.get_full_path) is True:
    valor = request.get_full_path()
```

Eso solo si no sabes si es una función o método, del resto, si sabes no llames el `callable` si no simplemente llama tu función con los paréntesis al final. En este caso, ya te dije que es un método. Así no tienes que hacer el `replace` que estas haciendo.

Luego algo que te falta, es entender los querysets. Lastimosamente no podré explicarte eso porque hay muchos tutoriales en internet, además de la misma documentación de django que es la mejor en explicarlo. Pero básicamente viene la parte de sacar los datos de la base de datos para que puedas mostrarlos en tu vista. Django hace esto gracias a los querysets y su api. Pero para darte una idea puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
from django.db.models import Q

url = request.get_full_path()

query = request.GET.get('search_box', '')
q = Q(material__icontains=query) | Q(mina__icontains=query)
queryset = Mine180.objects.filter(q)

dicty = {
    "minerales": queryset, "search_query": query, "valor_pasado": url
}
return render(request, 'mine180/result.html', dicty)
```

Como no sé tus modelos, inventé los campos como `material` y `mina` pero tu debes poner los campos de acuerdo a lo que quieras buscar y filtrar.

Cualquier duda comenta

Comment: Gracias porque si no llegas a guiarme un poco seguía la documentación de django de los form, e iba a usar el método post (porque la información suele ser sensible), pero siendo mi base de datos pública no creo que tenga sentido usar un token de seguridad para hacer una búsqueda. trataré de pasar la query en el diccionario como en el ejemplo, y si tengo problemas te comento.